# Rails associations SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a User model and a SkillList model.

Association - `has_many / belongs_to`.

*So I can find the skill list entry for one user:*

```
current_user.skill_list
```

The user table has fields: `id`, `name` and `location`.

I need to query the database to find all users who have location and skills.

*I can find all users with an existing location (not including current user):*

```
users = User.where.not(location: nil, id: current_user.id)
```

**But how to exclude users without skills?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use `joins`, which by default performs SQL `INNER JOIN`, which is exactly what you need in this case:

```
User.where.not(location: nil).joins(:skill_list)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need!
I could not understand where to set `joins`.
Thanks.